# Округление с помощью элементарных арифметических операций

Tags: c++, математика, арифметика

Как выполнить округление с помощью элементарных арифметических операций?
Нужно выполнить округление до ближайшего целого
У меня есть следующий код:

```
int main ()
{
    double x;
        cout<<"vvedite neceloe chislo= ";
    cin >> x;
        cout<<"celaya chast' chisla = ";
    // получим целую часть числа х
    if(x >= 0)cout << floor(x) << endl;
    if(x < 0) cout << ceil(fabs(x)) << endl;
       cout<<"okryglennoe do blizhajshego= ";

    //число х, округленное до ближайшего целого
    if(x >= 0)cout << floor(x) << endl;
    if(x < 0) cout << ceil(x) << endl;


system("pause");
    return 0;}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например...

Округлим число "пи" до трех знаков после запятой.

```
double pi = 3.14159265358;

pi = int(pi*1000+0.5)/1000.0;
```

Устроит? :)

P.S. Вы бы как-то поточнее писали - какие числа, диапазон, тип, как округлять - к большему, к меньшему, к ближайшему... А так - догадывайся, что же именно вы хотели :(

**Update**

До ближайшего целого - это, грубо, до 0 знаков после запятой - так что просто

```
int(x + ((x < 0) ? -0.5 : 0.5))
```

А вообще-то этим занимается стандартная функция `round()`...

Comment: У меня есть следующий код, и как сделать тут округление? Задание: Дано действительное число Х. Получить Х округлив до ближайшего целого, использовать только элементарные арифм. операции ` double x;
        cout<<"vvedite neceloe chislo= ";
    cin >> x;
        cout<<"celaya chast' chisla = ";
    // получим целую часть числа х
    if(x >= 0)cout << floor(x) << endl;
    if(x < 0) cout << ceil(fabs(x)) << endl;
       cout<<"okryglennoe do blizhajshego= ";

    //число х, округленное до ближайшего целого
    if(x >= 0)cout << floor(x) << endl;
    if(x < 0) cout << ceil(x) << endl;`

Comment: Допишите это в вопрос

Comment: @ARHovsepyan дописал, хотелось бы узнать как выполнить в этом случае округление до ближайшего с помощью элементарных арифм. операций

Comment: Тогда лучше 0.5 * pow(10.0,-n)

Comment: @nathanprescott Ну, смотрите дополнение к ответу по вновь открывшимся обстоятельствам... Да, раз уж вы код в вопрос добавили - можете этот комментарий с кодом удалить.